# Does pandas read the whole file even when usecols is used?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to read a file inside a rest service. The file is huge with more than 100 columns. But I only want to read just first two columns. I know I can use **usecols** in read_csv but I was wondering how exactly it works?

Does pandas read the whole file and filter out the required columns?
Or does it only read the required columns?

I'm asking because I don't want to overload the memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation, it will read the whole file (no way to only read columns from disk), but will only parse and store the columns given in the `use_cols` variable (emphasize mine):

> usecols : list-like or callable, optional
>
> Return a subset of the columns... **Using this parameter results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage**.

Answer (score 3):

Using the parameter greatly reduces the parse time, and what you get has a smaller impact on memory.

You can see it in the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random_integers(1, 20, (1000000, 100))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
df.to_csv('testing.csv')

%timeit x = pd.read_csv('testing.csv')
7.38 s ± 86.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit x = pd.read_csv('testing.csv', usecols=[0, 1])
2.91 s ± 19.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```