# Does pandas read the whole file before returning requested col using usecols param or read requested cols only?

Tags: pandas

When reading csv (`read_csv`) with param `usecols` does pandas read the whole file and then return requested cols or read requested cols only? This question is about RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  [this answer to a question similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650088/21283023):

> According to the documentation, it will read the whole file (no way to only read columns from disk), but will only parse and store the columns given in the [`usecols`] variable (emphasize mine):
>
> > usecols : list-like or callable, optional
> >
> > Return a subset of the columns... **Using this parameter results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage**.

The documentation for `pandas.read_csv()` can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).